# How to create multiple product using magento API

Tags: product, rest-api, magento2.4

How to create/import multiple products via Magento API.

I have created a single product using the following API

http://127.0.0.1/magento240/rest/V1/products

Answer (score 0):

For bulk calls you can use the `DOMAIN_NAME/rest/async/bulk/V1/ENDPOINT` URL

Do know that this uses cron/supervisor to process the products on the server you are running Magento. So you need something in place to handle incoming calls.

You can use the documentation to see what should be POSTed as a minimum to create a product:
https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.3-admin/tag/products#operation/catalogProductRepositoryV1SavePost

The only difference with bulk is you need to POST an array in stead of the singular "entity"

Comment: I am having doubt on Payload data to import products. do you have sample